# Filters vs $_POST (or $_GET)

Tags: php, filter

Which one are you supposed to use, to check if a form submit button has been clicked?

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Sign Up">
```

1. `if (isset($_POST['action'] && $_POST['action'] == "Sign Up") ...`
   or
2. `if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action')) && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action') == "Sign Up")`

NB: I use $_POST['action] == 'Sign Up', because I use the 'action' array for delete and logout as well, and because some of my forms have two submit buttons, so I can differentiate).

Comment: Does the second one actually parse?

Comment: @mario: no it won't. It's a parse error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `<form method="post" ...>`, you should use `$_POST`. You can check for a single field, for example:

```
if ( isset($_POST['action']) )
```

or any field:

```
if ( 0 < count($_POST) )
```

or check request method:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
```

or a combination of above :)

I don't recommend checking submit button's value, if it changes, you need to modify the code as well. Not to mention what will you need to do if the site is or becomes multi lingual.

Comment: `0 < count()`? Why not `count() > 0`?

Comment: I got used to this form a long time ago, there is no difference except for readability. 0 could even be omitted, only `if ( count($_POST) )` is actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not actually answering the question. But I would give the different submit-buttons different `name`'s, so they are not bound to the value which is displayed on the button. Which in turn makes it less error prone to change the text on the button.

For instance `name='signup'` or `name='action[signup]'`.

And check with `isset($_POST['signup'])` or `isset($_POST['action']['signup'])` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think I bumped into this problem once: 
Forms can be posted by pressing enter, in which case no value for the button is posted. So I would strongly discourage to use three different submit buttons for three such different actions. Instead, I'd use three forms, and use another way to distinguish between them, like putting a hidden field in them or posting to a different url (or put something like `?action=signup` in the forms `action` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the exact value of an input you want while expecting a very specific value, just use #1.

Using filters can save the amount of code needed.  As opposed to writing out all the code needed to check if an IP address you're given is, say not on a private range, you can reduce the code to just this...

```
$var = "192.168.2.1";
echo (int) filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE); // 0
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php for additional filter types and option flags.  Additionally, you can pass the value to a [callback function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php) to customize how you filter data.

You can also change/sanitize the input with less code.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

```
$var = "te)st@test.com";
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // "test@test.com"
```

Though using filter_x functions allows for writing out less code, I personally have no idea how it performs compared to being handled by actual verbose code nor do I personally know exactly how reliable the filters and sanitizers are.

Comment: filter_var() works well if you know which to use. They're definitely faster than roll-your-own solutions, not that it should matter for security issues. But the API is so clumsy and verbose that few people use them in practice. I'm advocating [new OOP input() vars](http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/wiki/input/) which allow `$_GET->ip["adr"]` or just `$_POST->email["field"]` for easier and thus less reluctant use.

Comment: @mario: pretty cool, especially with the chaining.  I'd prefer a bool `$_POST->field->is_valid` approach.  Basically jumping off the actual field names, sometimes using filters for value checks instead of value changes.  It looks like with a simple tweak, you could also add in function overloading - letting the user `add` anon filter functions with a custom function name.  Sadly, it's not as easy as `$obj->property = function () {/* */};`, but at least it is as easy as `function __call($fnc, $args) {$this->cst_fnc[$fnc]($args);}`.  Though I might be getting carried away.

Comment: Actually I thought about adding that. While `$_POST->is_int["field"]` is already possible (picks up global functions), it needs nicer wrapper methods to not break the chaining, and be readable. In theory you can here already add `$_POST->myfunc=function($data){return "$data";}` custom methods. Using only generic filter functions isn't really workable anyway; you'll need application-specific validation. Though it can never really solve all issues. Some verifications need broader application logic.

Comment: @mario: my bad - you're right.  It is as easy as `$_POST->myfunc=function($data){return "$data";}` through `__set()`.  You'll still need to add the custom functions to an array property accessed through `__call()` rather than just setting a property.  Using a property alone as a function always fails fatally, even when that property is an object with an `__invoke()` method.  Still there's the problem of `$this` being out of scope in anon functions.

Comment: I admit I haven't really tried that. 8} But true, that's also an issue with PHP - you cannot have unbound methods like in Python, `$this` is never accessible. But maybe there is a way via closures? But anyway, I would just use a per-project customized version and hack application-specific filter methods in. Due to modified semantics it's not always applicable anyway. And if generic sanitization suffices for a project, I think PHPs `filter_input_array()` is actually quite okay, if you can define a ruleset and filter all at once.

Answer (score 0):

For just checking if it's there, you don't need `filter_var`.  `isset` alone is sufficient.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 use `isset()` in his examples

Comment: @Harmen: ah, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the right one:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'] && $_POST['action'] == "Sign Up") ...
```

Because using a function in `isset` will trigger a parse error. Only variables can be used with `isset` and other language constructs like `empty`.